# ParametricPlot of curve with one dimensional domain

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

For a mapping $\gamma(x,y)$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ we can plot the image of some two dimensional region with `ParametricPLot` as, for instance,

```
\[Gamma][x_, y_] := {x^2, x*y^3}
 ParametricPlot[\[Gamma][x, y], Element[{x, y}, Disk[]], PlotRange -> All]
```

being the domain, say, a disk. But if I want to plot just the image of the boundary as

```
ParametricPlot[\[Gamma][x, y], Element[{x, y}, Circle[]], PlotRange -> All]
```

then `ParametricPlot` has troubles understanding the dimensionality and the number of variables. Then, how can one make a parametric plot, being the domain some curve, as in the previous example ?

Note: I do not want to parametrize the circle as $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ and then replace back to get $\gamma(\theta)$, because this may not be possible for more complicated curves without closed, analytical formula.

Comment: `ParametricPlot[\[Gamma][x, y], Element[{x, y}, Disk[]], 
 PlotRange -> All, BoundaryStyle -> Red, PlotStyle -> None]`

Comment: @cvgmt True. But my question comes from the fact that the function is some numerical, slowly running bunch of things and running for the whole interior, which I don't need, is unnecessary, so just want to compute the values of the boundary.

Comment: `reg = ParametricRegion[{\[Gamma][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] 
     Circle[]}, {x, y}];
Region[Style[reg, Red]]`

Comment: @cvgmt - what version are you using? With v13.1 on a Mac, I don't get a plot

Comment: @BobHanlon  I am using  v13.1 on Win 11 and  v13.1 on Manjaro Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- draw a circle and mapping it by `γ[x_, y_] = {x^2, x*y^3}`

```
Clear[circle,γ];
circle= RegionPlot[DiscretizeRegion[Circle[], AccuracyGoal -> 3]];
γ[x_, y_] = {x^2, x*y^3};
circle /. {x_Real, y_Real} -> γ[x, y]
```

[image]

- Use `ParametricRegion` as in comment.

```
reg = ParametricRegion[{γ[x, y], {x, y} ∈ 
     Circle[]}, {x, y}];
RegionPlot[DiscretizeRegion[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> .0001], 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may first generate a parametrized region. From the result you then calculate the boundary using "RegionBoundary". Here is your example:

```
reg = ParametricRegion[{\[Gamma][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[]}, {x,
    y}]
Region[Style[reg, Red]] (*show the region*)
Region[RegionBoundary[reg]] (* show the border *)
```

[image]

If you want to increase the performance, you may only calculate a small strip. The drawback is, that the border is then 2 sided:

```
reg = ParametricRegion[{\[Gamma][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] 
     RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 1], Disk[{0, 0}, 0.998]] }, {x, y}];
Region[Style[reg, Red]] (*show the region*)
Region[RegionBoundary[reg]] (* show the border *)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But my question comes from the fact that the function is some numerical, slowly running bunch of things and running for the whole interior, which I don't need, is unnecessary, so I just want to compute the values of the boundary

Comment: Look at my answer again. I added way to decrease the amount of calculation to my answer.

Comment: Nice. That's an ingenious solution.